# How to prevent overwriting an object someone else has modified

Tags: python, django, django-models, locking, blocking

I would like to find a generic way of preventing to save an object if it is saved after I checked it out.

We can assume the object has a `timestamp` field that contains last modification time. If I had checked out (visited a view using a ModelForm for instance) at `t1` and the object is saved again at `t2`, given `t2` > `t1` I shouldn't be able to save it.

Comment: You want to prevent yourself from doing something? Why just not save it twice?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320096/django-how-can-i-protect-against-concurrent-modification-of-data-base-entries

Comment: @nosklo: a web application is typically multi-user, so I'm not necessarily preventing myself. I want to prevent saving on someone else's modifications without noticing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwrite the save method that would first check the last timestamp:

```
def save(self):
    if(self.id):
        foo = Foo.objects.get(pk=self.id)
        if(foo.timestamp > self.timestamp):
            raise Exception, "trying to save outdated Foo" 
    super(Foo, self).save()
```

Comment: a race condition can occur between the timestamp if check and the sql update query. the condition should be part of the update query which is atomic.

Comment: Beware, this answer is not correct for the reason Andrei stated above!! It will land you in serious trouble if you use it in production.  See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320096/django-how-can-i-protect-against-concurrent-modification-of-database-entries