# is database locking enabled by default in django?

Tags: django

Some frameworks are opinionated when it comes to database locking.  For example, grails orm (gorm) documents state the following:

> By default GORM classes are configured for optimistic locking

***Source***: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking

I've read through some material online for django and my understanding is that django does not provide locking by default.  Some examples:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/
- [Concurrency control in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645269/concurrency-control-in-django-model)
- [Django: How can I protect against concurrent modification of database entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320096)

(The above questions are different to this one.  *Those* questions are asking how you manage concurrency. *This* question is asking *what* is the default concurrency control.)

What is django's default approach to database locking? It seems that database locking is not enabled by default in django?

---

**NOTE**: This is NOT a question about which approach is best, it is a question to confirm django's approach to locking.

Comment: If this question does not fit stackoverflow's requirements, and you down vote it please let me know why so that I can improve the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: How can I protect against concurrent modification of database entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320096/django-how-can-i-protect-against-concurrent-modification-of-database-entries)

Comment: @KishorPawar: _that_ question is asking *how* you manage concurrency.  _this_ question is asking *what* is the default concurrency control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option in Django (though implementing a similar mechanism yourself is rather easy).

Do note, however, that what GORM calls "Optimistic Locking" has little to do with database locking (that's the point of it being optimistic).

You'll probably want to have a look at the [documentation page on transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/) for more DB internals documentation.