# Does race condition(lost update or write skew) happen in Django admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, race-condition

In **Django views**, we can use [**`select_for_update()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) to prevent **race condition(lost update or write skew)** so **race condition** doesn't happen in **Django views** with [**`select_for_update()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update). *I used **Django 3.2.16**.

But, even though I googled, I couldn't find any information saying *"in **Django admin**, race condition doesn't happen or [**`select_for_update()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) is used to prevent **race condition**"*.

So, in **Django admin**, does race condition happen?

- If yes, are there any ways to prevent **race condition** in **Django admin**?
- If no, is [**`select_for_update()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) or other way used to prevent **race condition** in **Django admin**? and can I see the code for me?

Answer (score 3):

By default in **Django Admin**, **lost update** or **write skew** caused by **race condition** can happen because `select_for_update()` is not used. *[**My answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826714/lost-update-vs-write-skew/73847878#73847878) explains **lost update** and **write skew**.

So, I wrote the example code with `select_for_update()` to prevent **lost update** or **write skew** in **Django Admin** as shown below. *I used **Django 3.2.16** and **PostgreSQL**:

### <**Lost update**>

For example, you create **`store_product` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`stock`** with **`models.py`** as shown below:

#### `store_product` table:

| id | name | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Apple** | **10** |
| **2** | **Orange** | **20** |

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
```

Then, you need to override [**get_queryset()**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L412) with `select_for_update()` in `ProductAdmin():` as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        
        last_part_of_referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER').split('/')[-2]
        last_part_of_uri = request.build_absolute_uri().split('/')[-2]

        if (last_part_of_referer == "change" and last_part_of_uri == "change"):
            qs = qs.select_for_update()
        
        return qs
```

Then, if you change(update) **product** as shown below:

[image]

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE` queries** are run in **transaction** according to **the PostgreSQL query logs** as shown below. *You can check [**how to log PostgreSQL queries**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

And, if you don't override `get_queryset()` in `ProductAdmin():` as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

**`SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries** are run as shown below:

[image]

### <**Write skew**>

For example, you create **`store_doctor` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`on_call`** with **`models.py`** as shown below:

#### `store_doctor` table:

| id | name | on_call |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** | **True** |
| **2** | **Lisa** | **True** |

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    on_call = models.BooleanField()
```

Then, you need to override [**response_change()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change) with `select_for_update()` and [**save_model()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) in `DoctorAdmin():` as shown below. *At least one doctor must be on call:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Doctor
from django.db import connection

@admin.register(Doctor)
class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).select_for_update().filter(on_call=True)
        obj_length = len(qs)

        if obj_length == 0:
            obj.on_call = True
        obj.save()

        return super().response_change(request, obj)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        last_part_of_path = request.path.split('/')[-2]

        if last_part_of_path == "add":
            obj.save()
```

Then, if you change(update) **doctor** as shown below:

[image]

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE` queries** are run in **transaction** but I don't know how to remove **the 1st `SELECT` query** in light blue as shown below:

[image]

And, if you don't override `response_change()` and `save_model()` in `DoctorAdmin():` as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Doctor

@admin.register(Doctor)
class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

**`SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries** are run as shown below:

[image]

For example for `write skew` again, you create **`store_event` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`user`** with **`models.py`** as shown below:

#### `store_event` table:

| id | name | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Make Sushi** | **John** |
| 2 | **Make Sushi** | **Tom** |

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Then, you need to override `response_add()` with `select_for_update()` and `save_model()` in `EventAdmin():` as shown below. *Only 3 users can join **the event "Make Sushi"**:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Event
from django.db import connection

@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).select_for_update() \
                                          .filter(name="Make Sushi")
        obj_length = len(qs)

        if obj_length < 3:
            obj.save()

        return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        last_part_of_path = request.path.split('/')[-2]

        if last_part_of_path == "change":
            obj.save()
```

Then, if you add **event** as shown below:

[image]

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `INSERT` queries** are run in **transaction** as shown below:

[image]

And, if you don't override [**response_add()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add) and `save_model()` in `EventAdmin():` as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Event

@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Only **`INSERT` query** is run as shown below:

[image]

You can also see my posts below about **SELECT FOR UPDATE** in Django:

- [**How to run "SELECT FOR UPDATE" instead of "SELECT" when adding data in Django Admin?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74831244/how-to-run-select-for-update-instead-of-select-when-adding-data-in-django-ad)
- [**How to run "SELECT FOR UPDATE" instead of "SELECT" when changing and deleting data in Django Admin?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74807372/how-to-run-select-for-update-instead-of-select-when-changing-and-deleting-da)
- [**How to run "SELECT FOR UPDATE" for the default "Delete selected" in Django Admin Actions?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74857394/how-to-run-select-for-update-for-the-default-delete-selected-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a race condition can occur in Django admin if multiple users try to update the same object at the same time. This can result in lost updates or write skew, where the final value of the object is not what was intended. To avoid this, Django admin uses optimistic locking to ensure that updates are performed safely and consistently. This means that if two users try to update the same object simultaneously, one of the updates will be rejected and the user will need to retrieve the latest version of the object and try again.

Comment: I couldn't find such information `Django admin uses optimistic locking to ensure that updates are performed safely and consistently` in Django documentation. Are there such information in Django documentation?