# How to run "SELECT FOR UPDATE" instead of "SELECT" when changing and deleting data in Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, select-for-update

I have the code below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, when changing data as shown below:

[image]

`SELECT` is run instead of `SELECT FOR UPDATE` as shown below. *I use **PostgreSQL** and these logs below are **the queries of PostgreSQL** and you can check [**On PostgreSQL, how to log queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

And, when clicking **`Delete` button** of **Change person** as shown below:

[image]

Then clicking **`Yes, I'm sure` button** to delete data as shown below:

[image]

`SELECT` is run instead of `SELECT FOR UPDATE` as shown below:

[image]

Now, I want to run `SELECT FOR UPDATE` instead of `SELECT` for both cases as shown above.

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [**get_queryset()**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L412) with [**select_for_update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        
        last_part_of_referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER').split('/')[-2]
        last_part_of_uri = request.build_absolute_uri().split('/')[-2]

        if (last_part_of_referer == "change" and last_part_of_uri == "change") or \
           (last_part_of_referer == "delete" and last_part_of_uri == "delete"):
            qs = qs.select_for_update()
        
        return qs
```

Then, when changing data as shown below:

[image]

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` is run instead of `SELECT` as shown below:

[image]

And, when clicking **`Delete` button** of **Change person** as shown below:

[image]

Then clicking **`Yes, I'm sure` button** to delete data as shown below:

[image]

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` is run instead of `SELECT` as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To run a SELECT FOR UPDATE query instead of a regular SELECT query in Django Admin, you can use the select_for_update() method on your queryset. This method will lock the rows in the queryset until the transaction is committed or rolled back, preventing other transactions from modifying the data in those rows.