# How to run "SELECT FOR UPDATE" instead of "SELECT" when adding data in Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, select-for-update

In `PersonAdmin():` below, I overrode [**response_add()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add) with [**select_for_update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) so that [**write skew**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73847878/8172439) doesn't occur then only 2 persons can be added on **Add person** and overrode [**save_model()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) so that `obj.save()` works only when changing a person on **Change person**:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
                                                 # Here
        obj_count = super().get_queryset(request).select_for_update().all().count()
        
        if obj_count < 2:
            obj.save()

        return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        last_part_of_path = request.path.split('/')[-2]

        if last_part_of_path == "change":
            obj.save() # Here
```

But, when adding a person on **Add person** as shown below:

[image]

`SELECT` is run instead of `SELECT FOR UPDATE` as shown below. *I use **PostgreSQL** and these logs below are **the queries of PostgreSQL** and you can check [**On PostgreSQL, how to log queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

So, how can I run `SELECT FOR UPDATE` instead of `SELECT` when adding a person on **Add person**?

Answer (score 0):

[**select_for_update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) doesn't work with [**count()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count):

```py
                                         # Here                    # Here
obj_count = super().get_queryset(request).select_for_update().all().count()
```

But, [**select_for_update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) works with [**len()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
                    # Here                           # Here
        obj_count = len(super().get_queryset(request).select_for_update().all())
        
        if obj_count < 2:
            obj.save()

        return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): # Here
        last_part_of_path = request.path.split('/')[-2]

        if last_part_of_path == "change":
            obj.save() # Here
```

So, when adding a person on **Add person** as shown below:

[image]

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` is run instead of `SELECT` as shown below:

[image]