# How to run "SELECT FOR UPDATE" for the default "Delete selected" in Django Admin Actions?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions, select-for-update

I have **`Person` model** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And, this is **`Person` admin** below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, when clicking **Go** to go to delete the selected persons as shown below:

[image]

Then, clicking **Yes I'm sure** to delete the selected persons:

[image]

Only **`DELETE` query** is run in transaction as shown below:

[image]

Now, how can I run `SELECT FOR UPDATE` for **the default "Delete selected"** in **Django Admin Actions**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override [**delete_queryset()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_queryset) with `@transaction.atomic` as shown below to run `SELECT FOR UPDATE` for **the default "Delete selected"** in **Django Admin Actions**. *`print(qs)` is important to run `SELECT FOR UPDATE`:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.db import transaction
from django.db import connection

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @transaction.atomic # Here
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        ids = []
        
        for obj in queryset:
            ids.append(obj.id)
        
        qs = queryset.select_for_update().filter(id__in=ids)
        print(qs) # <- Important to run "SELECT FOR UPDATE"
        qs.delete()
```

Then, when clicking **Go** to go to delete the selected persons as shown below:

[image]

Then, clicking **Yes I'm sure** to delete the selected persons:

[image]

**`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query** and **`DELETE` query** are run in transaction as shown below:

[image]

In addition, you can use **raw queries** as shown below if you want to run shorter queries:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.db import transaction
from django.db import connection

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @transaction.atomic # Here
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        ids = ()
        qs_length = len(queryset)
        
        if qs_length > 1:
            for obj in queryset:
                ids += (obj.id,)
            ids = str(ids)
        elif qs_length == 1:
            ids = "(" + str(queryset[0].id) + ")"
        else:
            return

        with connection.cursor() as cursor: # Here
            query = "SELECT * FROM store_person WHERE id IN " + ids + " FOR UPDATE"
            cursor.execute(query)
            query = "DELETE FROM store_person WHERE id IN " + ids
            cursor.execute(query)
```

Then, when clicking **Go** to go to delete the selected persons as shown below:

[image]

Then, clicking **Yes I'm sure** to delete the selected persons:

[image]

**shorter `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query** and **shorter `DELETE` query** are run in transaction as shown below:

[image]

In addition, you can check the default code of [**delete_queryset()**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1234) which is not overridden as shown below:

```py
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    
    # ...
    
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """Given a queryset, delete it from the database."""
        queryset.delete()
```