# Django: Is there a way to prevent a view from being called twice simultaneously?

Tags: python, django

There's some functionality on our Django app that displays a link to refresh some information from our version control system.  This is simply a link, and when they hit that URL the actions of going to version control, getting the information, checking it against the database and updating the database are performed.

Recently we had a user click the 'refresh' button twice for one asset.  This resulted in the URL being hit twice, so the operations were performed twice and eventually a duplicate entry was created in our database.

We need to do something to remove the possibility of the user clicking that button twice.  Should we move from a link to a javascript button?  Should we set some flag in request.session as soon as the first click happens, then unset it upon completion, and always check that flag when performing a refresh?  Those are just two ideas that seem feasible, but I really don't know.

Comment: Why is a page request, causing a database entry? I'm guessing it's not a POST.

Comment: Oops.  This is our first webapp, but I should've caught that.  Yeah - this is a get.  There's a column where we generate either a 'view' link (if our DB is up to date with VC) or a 'refresh' link (if our DB is not up to date with VC).  The 'view' is clearly a GET, but 'refresh' should be a POST.  Does that mean the model of having it be a link will not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `POST` request and redirect after it, really.

Also, to prevent double submitting, you can employ a solution like one from this question: [Does a library to prevent duplicate form submissions exist for django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136954/does-a-library-to-prevent-duplicate-form-submissions-exist-for-django/2201400#2201400). You can store a key `refreshing_vcs` in `request.session` and check its value in your view. If the data is already being refreshed, then you can redirect user to another page and tell to wait a bit.

Completely another way would be to setup a `django-celery` task (or simply use cron) to perform updates at regular intervals automatically, but I don't know whether it suit your requirements.

Comment: Yeah, we're incorrectly using a GET here.  Changing to a POST and adding the a flag to the session seems like the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
         return render(request, 'get.html')
    def post(self, request):
        # handle your post here
        # maybe you had a form that was filled, handle it here
        # then instead of returning a HttpResponse
        # use a redirect, that way, a refresh won't result in the 
        # post method been called twice. 
        # note if you want, you can also safely redirect to the same view
        return redirect('/my-login-view')
```

[looking at the django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts.py#L33) the redirect functions arguments can be:
1. A model
2. A view name or
3. A URL

Answer (score -1):

That is the best solution, however you could disable the button onclick by adding a disabled attribute to the button equalling 'true'

With jQuery:
$('#yourButtonId').attr("disabled", true);