# assign unique id avoiding race conditions

Tags: django

I have a form called Vehicles and i'm trying to assign a unique id to each one, each time a user completes one.

```
class Vehicles(models.Model):
     id = models.DecimalField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
```

Trying to avoid race conditions(when two forms are being submitted in the same time) after the initial value that I assign to the id field according to the last vehicle-db-record, before saving the form I query again the db for the id of the last record. More or less I do it this way:

```
def vehicle(request):
    vehicles= Vehicles.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]
    id = vehicles.id+1

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VehiclesForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            vehicles= Vehicles.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]
            id = vehicles.id+1
            temp = form.save(new_veh_id=id)
            return render_to_response('success.html', locals(), context_instance= RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = VehiclesForm(initial={'id': id})
    return render_to_response('insertVehicle.html', locals(), context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

and in forms I override the save method:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        commit = kwargs.pop('commit', True)
        new_veh_id = kwargs.pop('new_veh_id', None)
        instance = super(VehiclesForm, self).save(*args, commit = False, **kwargs)

        if id is not None: instance.id = new_veh_id
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

but is_valid returns false with form error:vehicles with this id already exists. 
I use exactly this practice with another model and form (identical fields to these) and it works like a charm, forms pass validation despite the same id and it changes it in the last submitted form. Can anyone help me on this or suggest a better solution to achieve this functionality? What I do is maybe somehow 'custom'.

EDIT: I also tried this, but is_valid fails again

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(VehiclesForm, self).clean()
        id = unicode(self.cleaned_data.get('id'))

        vehicles= Vehicles.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]
        id = vehicles.id+1
        cleaned_data[id] = id

        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: why do you want to handle the unique values yourself? Consider using autofield https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: I'm working with a legacy db so I'm afraid that's not possible, or?

Comment: Then, in the view, vehicles= Vehicles.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]
    id = vehicles.id+1 would not help. You would have to modify in save() method. to avoid concurrency, some examples are given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320096/django-how-can-i-protect-against-concurrent-modification-of-database-entries

Comment: yes, but in order to reach save(), form should pass validation. But when two forms are being submitted in the same time from different users the ids are the same and the last one fails validation. this is my problem.

Comment: you can use the clean method to populate just before saving.

Comment: yes,I know that but again: form should pass is_valid first in order to call clean() or save() method and it doesn't in the case that I described. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: is_valid() calls clean() on the form automatically

Comment: @marlen have you considered [locking your table](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/833/)?

Comment: @karthikr u're right. Although check the edit.

Comment: cleaned_data['id'] as opposed to clean_data[id]

Comment: typo. It passed validation! Do u think that is sufficient or I should do it again in save()? Thank you for your help!

Comment: No you would not have to do it again. I would just do def clean_id(self):  and return the cleaned id, instead of def clean()

Comment: Do the ids have to be decimals? Perhaps using a GUID type identifier would work well in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update) which locks the rows until the end
of transaction. Mind you that although it is designated to work with many
rows, you can still lock just one row, by making sure your `filter` query
will return only one object.