# Django models - how to validate on basis of other instances of same model?

Tags: django, django-models

Every time there's an INSERT/UPDATE of this model I want to check that the 'personprofile' hasn't been committed to more a days work on that date ?

By 'committed' I mean I only want the update to continue if, after it's finished, the total of `proportion_of_day_required` on all instances of `PersonRequirement` with the same `personprofile` and the same `date` is 1.0 or less.

```
class PersonRequirement(models.Model):
    '''
    Joins a person to a Subproject on a given
    day and nominates how much of that day
    they are required for
    '''
    subproject = models.ForeignKey(SubProject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    personprofile = models.ForeignKey(PersonProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    proportion_of_day_required = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
```

I was looking at the save method on the model but I wasn't sure whether trying to read other instances of the same model would be OK while trying to insert/update an instance of the same model ?

Maybe there's a better way which I've overlooked ?

Comment: What do you mean by : been committed to more a days work on that date ?

Comment: @MaximeB: thanks for your response. I've added a paragraph to the question which I hope makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the save custom method for this one. The same custom method is used to create manual logic every time a save is done which also includes the update

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was hoping that you could speak to what, if any, locking issues might arise when trying to fetch other instances of the same model.

Comment: No issues will arise for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `save` method from your model, checking if saving meets your requirements, rejecting it if not.

About concurrent modifications, you will have to implement an optimistic lock (look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320096/django-how-can-i-protect-against-concurrent-modification-of-database-entries)), using versionning and rejecting update if another occured at the same time.

Hope I helped.