# Monitor Management Command Execution in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a Django app that uses a management command to pull data from various sources. The plan is to run this command hourly with cron, and also have it run on user command from a view (i.e. when they add a new item that needs data, I don't want them to wait for the next hour to roll around to see results). The question is:

How can I set up this command such that if it is already currently running, it won't execute? Is there some place where I can stash a variable that can be checked by the script before execution? My current best idea is to have the command monitor stdout for a while to make sure nothing else is executing, but that seems like a hack at best. This is the only task that will be running in the background.

I'm basically trying to avoid using Celery here.

Comment: Don't sweat Celery.  It's simple to set up and easy to run.  I used Redis as a MQ with minimal problems if RabbitMQ is your headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your read function in a try/except block marking some external memoization for execution control.  I'm using Redis as an example:

```
from redis import Redis

try:
    r_client = Redis() # assuming standard settings
    sentinel = r_client.incr("my_sentinel")
    if sentinel == 1:
        run_command()
    else:
        r_client.decr("my_sentinel")
except Exception as e:
    r_client.decr("my_sentinel")
    raise e
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid adding another data store. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280075/atomic-operations-in-django), atomic operations are doable in Django. Thoughts on using that instead?

Comment: Yes, that's something you can do but it requires a roundtrip to the database.  You can also do it with the filesystem, store the value in a [filelock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock/).  You can also use memcached (almost all the code is the same).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file named "i_am_running.log" at the beginning of your management command and remove it at the end if it. When running same management command, check for its' presence. In case of no exist - go further. Otherwise - abort.

Comment: This is too simple if it is vital to have only one running instance.  It's too vulnerable to race conditions.  You need something atomic to insure a single running instance.