# How to do DB memcaching in Django with derived data?

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, database-caching

***NOTE:***
This is a detailed question asking how best to implement and manage Database caching in my web-application with memcached. This question uses Python/Django to illustrate the data-models and usage, but the language is not really that relevant. I'm really more interested in learning what the best strategy to maintain cache-coherency is. Python/Django just happens to be the language I'm using to illustrate this question.

***RULES OF MY APPLICATION:***

1. I have a 3 x 3 grid of cells of integers
2. The size of this grid may increase or decrease in the future. Our solution must scale.
3. Their is a cumulative score for each row that is calculated by summing `(value * Y-Coord)` for each cell in that row.
4. Their is a cumulative score for each column that is calculated by summing `(value * X-Coord)` for each cell in that column.
5. The values in the cells change infrequently. But those values and the scores scores are read frequently.
6. I want to use `memcached` to minimize my database accesses.
7. I want to minimize/eliminate storing duplicate or derived information in my database

The image below shows an example of the state of the my grid.

[image]

***MY CODE:***

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)

class Cell(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    y = models.IntegerField(editable=False)

    # Whenever this value is updated, the keys for the row and column need to be 
    # invalidated. But not sure exactly how I should manage that.
    value = models.IntegerField()


class Row(models.Model):
    y = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def cummulative_score(self):
        # I need to do some memcaching here.
        # But not sure the smartest way to do it.
        return sum(map(lambda p: p.x * p.value, Cell.objects.filter(y=self.y)))

class Column(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def cummulative_score(self):
        # I need to do some memcaching here.
        # But not sure the smartest way to do it.
        return sum(map(lambda p: p.y * p.value, Cell.objects.filter(x=self.x)))
```

***SO HERE IS MY QUESTION:***

You can see that I have setup a `memcached` instance. Of course I know how to insert/delete/update keys and values in `memcached`. But given my code above how should I name the keys appropriately? It won't work if the key names are fixed since there must exist individual keys for each row and column. And critically how can I ensure that the appropriate keys (and only the appropriate keys) are invalidated when the values in the cells are updated?

How do I manage the cache invalidations whenever anyone updates Cell.values so that the database accesses are minimized? Isn't there some django middleware that can handle this book-keeping for me? The [**documents**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) that I have seen don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# your client, be it memcache or redis, assign to client variable
# I think both of them use set without TTL for permanent values.

class Cell(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    y = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    value = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Cell.cache("row",self.y)
        Cell.cache("column",self.x)
        super(Cell, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def score(dimension, number):
        return client.get(dimension+str(number), False) or Cell.cache(number)

    @staticmethod
    def cache(dimension, number):
        if dimension == "row":
            val = sum([c.y * c.value for c in Cell.objects.filter(y=number)])
            client.set(dimension+str(self.y),val)
            return val

        if dimension == "column":
            val = sum([c.x * c.value for c in Cell.objects.filter(x=number)])
            client.set(dimension+str(self.x),val)
            return val

        raise Exception("No such dimension:"+str(dimension))
```

Comment: Can you please take my code from the question above and actually insert the statements to make it work? I still haven't gotten a clear example of how to manage the cache invalidations cleanly and atomically. Modification of my code above would help me the most.

Comment: You don't need row or column models, they just repeat data in Cell.

Comment: Ok. This is quite helpful. Thanks. However, does this code contain potential race conditions? I'm not 100% sure. But I think it might. How would I prevent race conditions if I was storing a dictionary as a value in the cache (like this `client.set("myKey", {"A":1, "B":2})`) and my application wanted to increment the value of B from 2 to 3? If two different web users triggered this same increment operation close in time, I think the value in B could get corrupted. How could I avoid that?

Comment: The operation I used is atomic on the row.  You never get a wrong answer for any given snapshot of the model but you might get a situation where if two increment operations are close enough in time (you did say that changing the value was infrequent), two threads might come to different conclusions and the thread with the older results might be the latter one to store it.  The odds are relatively low given the constraint you gave.  You can assign a keyvalue in your client a sentinel value indicating a set operation is in progress.

Comment: For an example of using a memcached sentinel see [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966645/monitor-management-command-execution-in-django/26968963#26968963)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cache individual row/column combinations you should append the object id to the key name.

given a x, y variables:

```
key = 'x={}_y={}'.format(x, y)
```

I would use the table name and just append the id, row id could just be the table PK, column id could just be the column name, like this

```
key = '{}_{}_{}'.format(table_name, obj.id, column_name)
```

In any case I suggest considering caching the whole row instead of individuals cells

Comment: But how do I manage the cache invalidations when the Cell.values is updated? Is there some django middleware that can handle this book-keeping for me? 

FYI, The documents that I have seen about using Django with memcached all seem to talk about how to cache the output of dynamic pages for me. I don't want toe cache that. I don't actually serve any pages. My app is just a series of callable rest-APIs. But I want those APIs to minimize database accesses. So I want my django models to cache their calls to the DB.

Comment: to invalidate you can just use time, for example set the cache valid for 1 second, so your database won't get more than 1 hit per second for this query

Answer (score 1):

The `Cell` object can invalidate cached values for its `Row` and `Column` when the model object is saved.

(`Row` and `Column` are plain objects here, not Django models, but of course you can change that if you need to store them in the database for some reason.)

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)

class Cell(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    y = models.IntegerField(editable=False)

    # Whenever this value is updated, the keys for the row and column need to be 
    # invalidated. But not sure exactly how I should manage that.
    value = models.IntegerField()

    def invalidate_cache(self):
        Row(self.y).invalidate_cache()
        Column(self.x).invalidate_cache()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Cell, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.invalidate_cache()


class Row(object):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    @property
    def cache_key(self):
        return "row_{}".format(self.y)

    @property
    def cumulative_score(self):
        score = mc.get(self.cache_key)
        if not score:
            score = sum(map(lambda p: p.x * p.value, Cell.objects.filter(y=self.y)))
            mc.set(self.cache_key, score)
        return score

    def invalidate_cache(self):
        mc.delete(self.cache_key)


class Column(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def cache_key(self):
        return "column_{}".format(self.x)

    @property
    def cumulative_score(self):
        score = mc.get(self.cache_key)
        if not score:
            score = sum(map(lambda p: p.y * p.value, Cell.objects.filter(x=self.x)))
            mc.set(self.cache_key, score)
        return score

    def invalidate_cache(self):
        mc.delete(self.cache_key)
```